# Setting PATH for 'ROOT' in Red Hat 5

Tags: bash, path, redhat

I have edited '/etc/profile' and added the following:

export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_21

However, when logged in as 'root': '# echo $JAVA_HOME' lists a different path.

How do I configure 'root' to pick the above path?

NB: Exporting paths in 'bashrc' or '.bash_profile', for root,  did not work for account 'root'.

Comment: By spelling the superuser's account with all caps you made me think you were talking about [ROOT](http://root.cern.ch/drupal/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are only a limited number of places where the value can be mis-set for root.  The home directory for the superuser is `/root`, so you should first look in `/root/.bashrc` and `/root/.bash_profile`.  You might need to look in `/etc/bashrc`, too.

If none of that yields enlightenment, you could try debugging where the environment is set by adding `set -x` (and perhaps `env`) to the top of `/etc/profile`, maybe only if the person running it is `root` (so as not to disturb other users), and track what is executed and set.  Use the `env` command to diagnose whether JAVA_HOME is already set on entry to `/etc/profile`.

The Bash manual (4.0 edition) says:

> #### §6.2 Bash Startup Files
>
> [...]
>
> When Bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a non-interactive shell with the
>   ‘--login’ option, it first reads and executes commands from the file ‘`/etc/profile`’, if
>   that file exists. After reading that file, it looks for ‘`~/.bash_profile`’, ‘`~/.bash_login`’,
>   and ‘`~/.profile`’, in that order, and reads and executes commands from the first one that
>   exists and is readable.

Unless you have done something unusual, root's `~` is `/root`.